# bootstrap Css design not properly working in desktop

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all bootstrap Css design not properly  working in desktop,

Here i am created sample html and bootstrap code on below, design doesn't shows properly in mobile view but not properly in  desktop View,
Thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>     
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>     
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1" ><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><label>Search Patient</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How it's properly not shown in desktop?

Comment: you also need to define col-md-? , col-lg-? ....

Comment: use `col-xs-?` and `col-md-?` for large n medium size device `md` will use n small and extra small `xs` will use

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 ">
    <label>Search Patient</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

just copy and paste this code it will work fine in all devices.
avoid using same id. id should be unique. Try exploring this link http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options you will get clear idea about the grid system in bootstrap. Hope this help your issue.